# when i convert my spring boot program as jar file and used thar jar file in another project i got error in repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.proretention.repository.LogRepository.save(Object)" because "this.logRepo" is null
    at com.proretention.service.LogService.save(LogService.java:27)
    at com.proretention.logger.LoggerTestApplication.main(LoggerTestApplication.java:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because your jar file only contains the classes of your project. You have to create a 'fat jar' which is a jar that also contains the dependencies of your project. If you are using Gradle the output of the 'bootJar' task is what you are looking for.

The 'jar' task creates a plain jar with the following name inside build/libs: "PROJECTNAME-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar" while the 'bootJar' task creates one with this name "PROJECTNAME-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", this is the one you need.